# Delete rows with extra delimiter from csv file in unix

Tags: regex, csv, unix

I have a csv file with 3 columns separated by ',' delimiter. Some values have , in data and I would like to remove the whole record. Suggest if I can do this using sed/awk,grep commands .

Input file :

- monitor,display,45
- keyboard,input,20
- loud,speaker,output,20
- mount,input,20

Expected Output :

- monitor,display,45
- keyboard,input,20
- mount,input,20

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: It is probably easier to use regex to extract what is valid rather than erase what is not. By example, in PHP, you can use `preg_match_all()` to extract all the valid rows in an array using that regex `/(?:(?:\w+,){2}\w+)/m` and iterate in the array to push back the data in a new file. Still in PHP, your CSV file can be overridden if you close your initial connection after fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

I used grep command to filter out rows with extra commas.

```
grep -v '.*,.*,.*,.*' input_file > output_file.
```

1. We need to define the regex pattern between .*
2. -v excludes the records which match the pattern specified.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you can do the same using **awk** , basically you want the record in which there are exactly 3 fields

```
$ awk -F, 'NF==3 {print $0}' data1.txt
monitor,display,45
keyboard,input,20
mount,input,20
```